# Vuetify data-table

Tags: datatables, vuetify.js

I have the following code:

```
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid full-height>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-data-table
            hide-actions
            :headers='headers'
            :items='items'
            class='elevation-1'
          ></v-data-table>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

in the script section:

```
data: {
headers: [
      {text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
    {text: 'Age', value: 'age'}
  ],
  items: [
      {
      name: 'John',
      age: 30
    }
  ]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/507618/

I do not understand why I'm just getting the header of the table and not the data.
Can someone help me?

[image: data-table]

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your table cells within the "items" slot of the v-data-table component. Headers render automatically, you can specify a "header" slot from customer headers. Checkout out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101) from the [Vuetify Docs on datatables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables). Notice the template within the v-data-table element that is defining the "items" slot.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define a slot with your table cells. In your code you have already added items props. You need to populate items inside a slot with data-table cells.

Here is your code with new changes.

```
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid full-height>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-data-table
            hide-actions
            :headers='headers'
            :items='items'
            class='elevation-1'
          >
           <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
             <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
             <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.age }}</td>
           </template>
         </v-data-table>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

If you need more information [read the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables)

Hope this helps.